# Is it possible to disable retry topic behaviour for perticular @kafkaListener method

Tags: apache-kafka, listener, consumer

Hi there I am new to Kafka i was going through Kafka retry topic configuration without @Retryable annotations So as u know with retry topic configuration it takes main topic from @kafkaListener and make retry and dlt topic and consume all topic based on scenario.
So my question here is it possible to have retry topic behaviour for one @kafkaListener method and normal behaviour to another @kafkaListener method ?

Motive behind questions is to read error topic independently.

```
@KafkaListener(id = "foo", topics = "myTopic")
    public void listen(String data) {
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

By this i know it will read mytopic , mytopic-error , mytopic-retry  based on configuration .

But i want another method for just error topic like this
And to somehow disable above behaviour

```
@KafkaListener(id = "foo-err", topics = "myTopic-error")
    public void listen(String data) {
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```